# Mosquitto broker not able to use access control

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

Here are my contents of acl_file

```
user client1
pattern read client2_topic

user client2
pattern write client2_topic

user client3
topic hello
```

I tried publishing message to topic `test` from client3 and he is publishing it.

I don't want any access to topics other than `client2_topic` and `hello`.

Comment: Can you update the question to include your mosquitto.conf and some of the mosquitto log output so we can see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

You should change `pattern` to `topic`. `pattern` applies to all clients and you would expect to see either `%c` or `%u` in the pattern string, otherwise there is no point to it.